# import scss file from jsx file in Plunker?

Tags: jspm, plunker

I'd like to be able to import scss files from inside a plunk

```
import './Box.scss!';
```

How should I config my setup to do that?

Link to failing sample:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dYcW8DsDF0GyT0SLef45?p=preview

throwing

```
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading https://registry.jspm.io/scss.js(…)
```